# If statement with url plus universal variable

Tags: javascript, url, variables, if-statement, character

I'm trying to transform a blog on blogger into a website. In order to have a static home page I am using the Javascript code below to see if the user is on the home page if they are then it will hide the post section and display a home page "gadget". Is anything supposed to match anything?

```
document.onload = hidepage();

function hidepage () {
 if (window.location == "http://website.blogspot.com/" || window.location == "http://website.blogspot.com/?zx=" + ANYTHING) { 
 //Checks to see if user is on the home page
  $(".hentry").hide(); //Hide posts
  $(".hfeed").hide(); //Hide posts
 }
 else {
  $("#HTML2").hide(); //hide gadget
 }

 $(".post-title").hide();  //Hide post titles
}
```

Comment: That's not a question, so I'm unsure of what you're wanting help with.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) in the second half of the `if` expression.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url === "http://website.blogspot.com/" || url.indexOf("http://website.blogspot.com/?zx=") === 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're saying I think you want to change the if condition to:

```
if (window.location.href === "http://website.blogspot.com/" || 
    window.location.href.indexOf("http://website.blogspot.com/?zx=") > -1)
```

You could also shorten this to:

```
 if (window.location.href === "http://website.blogspot.com/" || 
    window.location.href.indexOf("/?zx=") > -1)
```

Note that I've changed your `==` to `===` as the latter is a literal comparison.

Comment: It was a typo, was supposed to do `> -1`... location has no method of `indexOf` its supposed to be `location.href.indexOf`

Comment: Still, why not `=== 0`? Also, a `location` object is not a string, so `location === <any string>` will always be false. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: I didn't use `=== 0` as I'd rarely use the full URL including the http... my second example is what I'd tend to do. Just personal preference really.

Comment: It seems more logical to me that as the result could be 0, 1, 2, 3, 25, etc. that `> -1` is more suitable; as it better represents what I'm testing for (i.e. is the result a number that is more than `-1`). A test of `!= 1` would mean that in some crazy, impossible scenario a result of `"myimpossiblestring"` would return true. Even though its unlikely/impossible I don't feel comfortable writing that... its just personal preference.